# Payment method not showing for free product with paid shipping

Tags: payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway

I am a developer and stocked on this issue.

I can not see payment method with when i place a free product with paid shipping method.

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If your order total is `zero` then by default magento enable `zero checkout` payment method.

Comment: But shipping charge is not zero

Comment: is there customization for order total?  you are using one step checkout not default checkout. try with your default checkout.